# Getting a Discord Selfbot to join a server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Using Discord.js, how can I get a Selfbot to join a server using a link that someone sent me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
requests.post('discord.com/api/v7/invite/INVITECODE',{'Authorization':"TOKEN"})
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, and selfbotting is against the Discord's ToS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure if you are using your `account` as a selfbot you are already in the server and it should work. As Tenclea said it's against Discord's TOS so use this at your own risk

Comment: First, join the server then run selfbot